# How to modify a constraint using mvvmcross fluentLayout

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross, cirrious.fluentlayout

I've figuratively pulled my hair out on this one. I read from this article "http://gregshackles.com/fluentlayout-2-5/" that FluentLayout now supports constraint editing/removing but it doesn't seem to work on my end. My scenario is to toggle the visibility of a textfield within a UIView when a button is clicked.

I have tried the following.

**A. Modifying the height constraint**

```
 var height = isVisible ? textfield.Height().EqualTo(0) : textfield.WithSameHeight(textfieldContainer).Multiplier(1 / 3);
            textfieldContainer.Add(textfield);
            textfieldContainer.SubviewsDoNotTranslateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints();
            textfieldContainer.AddConstraints(
                    textfield.WithSameLeft(textfieldContainer).Plus(12),
                    textfield.WithSameTop(textfieldContainer).Plus(24),
                    textfield.WithSameWidth(textfieldContainer),
                    height
                );
```

**B. Using SetActive(false) - Tried this out of desperation**

```
 textfieldContainer.Add(textfield);
            textfieldContainer.SubviewsDoNotTranslateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints();
            textfieldContainer.AddConstraints(
                    textfield.WithSameLeft(textfieldContainer).Plus(12).SetActive(!isVisible),
                    textfield.WithSameTop(textfieldContainer).Plus(24).SetActive(!isVisible),
                    textfield.WithSameWidth(textfieldContainer).SetActive(!isVisible),
                    textfield.WithSameHeight(textfieldContainer).WithMultiplier(1 / 4).SetActive(!isVisible)
                );
```

**Expected outcome**

The textfield should be visible depending on the visibility

**Actual outcome**

The textfield's height never changes, thus it is always visible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that your `height` variable is set once during the page lifecycle, and does not get change after that point. A way of achieving what you need is the following:

Firstly, bind your button click to a command that changes the state of a `boolean` on your `ViewModel`, so that the `boolean`'s value changes when the button is clicked:

`bindingSet.Bind(yourButton).To(vm => vm.YourCommand);`

```
MvxCommand _yourCommand;
public MvxCommand YourCommand
    => _yourCommand ?? _yourCommand = new MvxCommand(ReverseMyBool);

void ReverseMyBool()
{
    YourBoolean = !YourBoolean;
}
```

If necessary, set `YourBoolean` to true during the construction of your `ViewModel`, depending on whether your want the field to be hidden during page load. Now that the `ViewModel` property holds an accurate true/false state for whether your `UITextField` should be hidden, bind the `UITextField` itself for `Hidden` to the boolean (you may need to use a [value converter](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/value-converters) to reverse the value - if `Hidden` is true, the view is invisible):

```
bindingSet.Bind(textfield).For(c => c.Hidden).To(vm => vm.YourBoolean);
```

Next, create `FluentLayout` variables that relate to both situations (your view being visible and being hidden), and apply both of them:

```
var textFieldWithOneThirdContainerHeight = textfield.WithSameHeight(textFieldContainer).WithMultiplier(1f /3f);
var textFieldWithZeroHeight = textField.Height().EqualTo(0f);

textfieldContainer.AddConstraints(textFieldWithOneThirdContainerHeight, textFieldWithZeroHeight, /*other constraints here*/);
```

And finally, bind the constraints for `Active` to the `boolean` on your `ViewModel` - note that one will need to be reversed with a converter:

```
bindingSet.Bind(textFieldWithOneThirdContainerHeight).For(c => c.Active).To(vm => vm.YourBoolean).WithConversion(new ReverseBooleanValueConverter());
bindingSet.Bind(textFieldWithZeroHeight).For(c => c.Active).To(vm => vm.YourBoolean);
```

`ReverseBooleanValueConverter` would look something like this:

```
public class ReverseBooleanValueConverter: MvxValueConverter<bool, bool>
{
    protected override bool Convert(bool value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) 
        => !value;
}
```

When `YourBoolean` is true, your `UITextField` should be invisible, and should have a height of `0f`. When `YourBoolean` is false, it should be visible, and should have one third the height of it's container.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks, perfect solution.